# "articulated in limb"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, countability

A line from the movie *A.I. Artificial Intelligence* grates a bit with "articulated in limb".

> The artificial being is a reality of perfect simulacrum, **articulated in limb**, articulate in speech, and not lacking in human response.

I am not sure what "limb" means in this sentence. If it refers to human appendages, shouldn't it be a count noun (according to various dictionaries) and be "limbs"? What does "articulated in limb" mean here?

Comment: If it was 'articulate in limb' it would be a more, er, articulate, witty phrase. I'm wondering if someone 'corrected' the original copy. 'articulate in limb, articulate in speech' means 'can move in a wiity, clever way - and talk that way too!' Which... would have been a nice turn of phrase. Wood have... Big difference one 'd' made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit awkward, but it's something of a play on the word "articulate", which has two meanings:

> 1. having or showing the ability to speak fluently and coherently.
> 2. having joints or jointed segments.

Technically, "articulated in limb" means no more than they "have joints", but it *implies* that they have the ability to move like human beings.  This is reflected in the second part, "articulate in speech", which implies that they also *talk* like human beings.

The statement is meant to be a kind of advertising, which often sounds good without necessarily making perfect sense.